# How to make a update query in Oracle using "With" statement shorter?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, with-statement

I'm building a update query.

But it seems quite messy because of useless duplicated "With" statements.

Do you any idea to make it shorter?

The sample query is below.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
   SET C1 = (
              WITH W_VIEW AS
              (
                SELECT *
                  FROM TABLE1
              )
              SELECT C_VALUE
                FROM W_VIEW
               WHERE ROWNUM = 1

            ) 

 WHERE C2 IN (

              WITH W_VIEW AS
              (
                SELECT *
                  FROM TABLE1
              )
              SELECT C2_VALUES
                FROM W_VIEW
               WHERE STH < 10

             );
```

I just want to use W_VIEW once.

For example,

```
WITH W_VIEW AS
(
    SELECT *
      FROM TABLE1
)
UPDATE TABLE1
   SET C1 = (SELECT C_VALUE FROM W_VIEW WHERE ROWNUM = 1) 
 WHERE C2 IN (SELECT C2_VALUES FROM W_VIEW  WHERE STH < 10)
```

.
I will be happy if that query is working :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one:

```
WITH w_view 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   table1) 
UPDATE (SELECT * 
        FROM   table1 
        WHERE  c2 IN (SELECT c2_values 
                      FROM   w_view 
                      WHERE  sth < 10)) 
SET    c1 = (SELECT c_value 
             FROM   w_view 
             WHERE  rownum = 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! But Missing Select Keyword error, ORA-00928, occurs. ;-<